# SoapUI failed to load URL for an XSD

Tags: soap, xsd, wsdl, soapui

I am trying to load wsdl file to SoapUI. But i get the below error.

Error loading [http://XXX.XXX.XXX.X:7180/VAL/BaseTypes.xsd]: java.lang.Exception: Failed to load url; http://XXX.XXX.XXX.X:7180/VAL/BaseTypes.xsd, 0

I have a xsd definition.

<xsd:include schemaLocation="http://XXX.XXX.XXX.X:7180/VAL/BaseTypes.xsd"/>

I changed to local path as below.

<xsd:include schemaLocation="C:\Users\sol\Desktop\BaseTypes.xsd"/>

But it mentions that the path is incorrect. What can be the solution.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the path as a URI: file:///C:/Users/sol/Desktop/BaseTypes.xsd"  ?

Comment: I have tried <xsd:include schemaLocation="C:\Users\sol\Desktop\BaseTypes.xsd"/>

Comment: OK - so why not try my suggestion as well?

Comment: Thanks. It worked